# Data from Text file without delimiter into list via python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, web-scraping

I am new to coding and I was trying web scraping and the operation was successful and was able to pull and convert into txt file. The content of the txt file looks like this,
"  1 United States $19,485,394,000,000 $19.485 trillion 2.27% 325,084,756 $59,939 24.08%   2 China $12,237,700,479,375 $12.238 trillion 6.90% 1,421,021,791 $8,612 15.12%   3 Japan $4,872,415,104,315 $4.872 trillion 1.71% 127,502,725 $38,214 6.02%

I want to convert this data into list like
[[ '1', 'United States',  '$19,485,394,000,000', '$19.485 trillion','2.27%','325,084,756','$59,939','24.08%'] and likewise for other data in the file.

I tried to split using space but the output is not in expected format,

**for temp in upd_tabl_new:**
**table_upd_list.append(temp)**

***Actual Output***: ['1', 'United', 'States', '$19,485,394,000,000', '$19.485', 'trillion', '2.27%', '325,084,756', '$59,939', '24.08%', '2', 'China'
but expecting an output like below,

[[ '1', 'United States',  '$19,485,394,000,000', '$19.485 trillion','2.27%','325,084,756','$59,939','24.08%']['2','China'....

Answer (score 1):

Replaces spaces in names ('Unites States') by a special symbol, example '_'.
Then, try to replace spaces in data by unique symbol (e.g. '#'), which is not appear in data. Use it as a delimiter further.

Answer (score 0):

The country name should be took cared.
Here is example code:

```
a = """1 United States $19,485,394,000,000 $19.485 trillion 2.27% 325,084,756 $59,939 24.08% 2 China $12,237,700,479,375 $12.238 trillion 6.90% 1,421,021,791 $8,612 15.12% 3 Japan $4,872,415,104,315 $4.872 trillion 1.71% 127,502,725 $38,214 6.02%"""

def get_splited(a):
    b = a.split()
    c = []
    # join words after split
    ind = 0
    cache_list = []
    while ind < len(b):
        if b[ind].isalpha():
            cache_list.append(b[ind])
        else:
            if cache_list:
                c.append(' '.join(cache_list))
                cache_list = []
            c.append(b[ind])
        ind += 1
        
    d = [c[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(c), 9)]
    return d
print(get_splited(a))
```

You could refer this link: https://onlinegdb.com/rJsPgUQHw

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to lack of new line in your data. If we have to work with this data, the solution is a dirty fix.

```
    fh = open('data.txt')
    content = fh.read()
    content = content.split()
    data = []
    newline = []
    counter = 1
    i=0
    while i < len(content):
        counter+=1
        newline.append(content[i])
        i+=1
        country=''
        while '$' not in content[i]:
          country += content[i] + ' '
          i += 1
        newline.append(country.rstrip())
        while True:
          try:
            next = content[i+1]
          except:
            next=''
          if next in ['trillion','billion','million']:
            text = content[i]+' '+content[i+1]
            i+=2
          else:
            text = content[i]
            i+=1
          newline.append(text)
          try:
            if content[i] == str(counter):
              data.append(newline)
              newline=[]
              break
          except:
              data.append(newline)
              break
    print(data)
```